# a small twist in the recursive mergesort in java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a mergesort program in java. Unfortunately my implementation gives a list of zero as the outcome of the code. I couldn't find the kink because everything seems logical and in the correct order to me. I would be grateful if someone can help me to find this glitch.

the code is as follows:

```
package com.company;

 public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = {35,43,21,4,23,1,13,44};

    System.out.println("initial array is equal to:");
    for (int data:array) {
        System.out.println(data);
    }
    mergeSort(array, new int[array.length], 0, array.length-1);
    System.out.println("Sorted array is equal to: " );
    for (int s:array) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    // arr = {35,43,21,4,23,1,13,44}
}

public static void mergeSort(int[] array,int[] secondaryArray,int leftStart, int rightEnd){
    if(leftStart >= rightEnd){
        return;
    }
    int midPoint = (leftStart + rightEnd) / 2;
    //sorting the left array
    mergeSort(array, secondaryArray, leftStart, midPoint);
    //sorting the right array
    mergeSort(array, secondaryArray, midPoint+1, rightEnd);
    //merging the sorted left and right array
    mergeHalves(array, secondaryArray,leftStart, rightEnd);
}

public static void mergeHalves(int[] array, int[] secondaryArray, int leftStart, int rightEnd){

    int leftEnd = (leftStart + rightEnd)/2;
    int rightStart = leftEnd + 1;
    int index = 0;

    while ((leftStart <= leftEnd) && (rightStart <= rightEnd)){
        if(array[leftStart] <= array[rightStart]){
            secondaryArray[index] = array[leftStart];
            leftStart++;
        }else {
            secondaryArray[index] = array[rightStart];
            rightStart++;
        }
        index++;
    }

    System.arraycopy(array,rightStart,secondaryArray,index,rightEnd-rightStart+1);
    System.arraycopy(array,leftStart,secondaryArray,index,leftEnd-leftStart+1);
    System.arraycopy(secondaryArray,0,array,0,secondaryArray.length);

}
}
```

Comment: You should do some debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a small bug- in `mergeHalves`, your final array copy is

```
System.arraycopy(secondaryArray,0,array,0,secondaryArray.length);
```

when it should be (assuming leftStartCopy is a copy of leftStart that is not changed during `mergeHalves`):

```
System.arraycopy(secondaryArray,0,array,leftStartCopy,rightEnd-leftStartCopy+1);
```

The problem is that you're copying all of `secondaryArray` onto `array`, instead of just the relevant cells. That is what caused `array` to be full of 0s.

Here is the full code of mergeHalves:

```
public static void mergeHalves(int[] array, int[] secondaryArray, int leftStart, int rightEnd){
int leftStartCopy = leftStart;
int leftEnd = (leftStart + rightEnd)/2;
int rightStart = leftEnd + 1;
int index = 0;

while ((leftStart <= leftEnd) && (rightStart <= rightEnd)){
    if(array[leftStart] <= array[rightStart]){
        secondaryArray[index] = array[leftStart];
        leftStart++;
    }else {
        secondaryArray[index] = array[rightStart];
        rightStart++;
    }
    index++;
}

System.arraycopy(array,rightStart,secondaryArray,index,rightEnd-rightStart+1);
System.arraycopy(array,leftStart,secondaryArray,index,leftEnd-leftStart+1);
System.arraycopy(secondaryArray,0,array,leftStartCopy,rightEnd-leftStartCopy+1);}
```

Comment: leftStart equals to zero, doesn't it?if it's true, therefore it doesn't matter to write zero or leftStart

Comment: by the way, I try to implement what you mentioned, but I go the 0s again

Comment: No, leftStart is different every time mergeHalves is called (the point of merge sort is that a different part of the array is dealt with each time). Further more, leftStart is changed during the execution of mergeHalves.

Comment: It worked for me... I will edit my answer with full code. One minute.

Answer (score 0):

Try running each part with sample inputs you control and see what you get. For example, run `mergeHalves` with different input arrays and see if you get what you expect.

Another thing you can do is make `mergeHalves` print its inputs and final result every time it's called. Then call `mergeSort` with small samples (empty array, array with 1 element, array with 2 elements, etc.) and you'll soon understand what your code is actually doing.